# How to determine efficacy of index on child side of foreign key

Tags: index-tuning

Given a parent-child relationship between two tables, such as:

```
table ORDER
    order_id PK (already indexed)
    order_name

table ITEM
    item_id PK (already indexed)
    order_id (FK to ORDER.order_id)
    amount
```

I want to determine whether there would be any benefit (performance improvement to SELECT queries) in adding an index on `ITEM.order_id`.

What information should I gather that would help me determine this? (such as structure of the queries my application runs against these tables, etc.) I do know that my application regularly runs queries that perform a simple inner join between these two tables. Are there any general principles that apply to index tuning for this kind of scenario?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three situations where you would want to index the child in addition to the parent in an FK/PK relationship:

1. If you ever select from `ITEM` based on `order_id` (obviously!)
2. If you ever run queries on from the JOIN of `ITEM` and `ORDERS` with a filter on `ORDERS`
3. As with 2, but with a filter on `ITEM` that is less selective than that on `ORDERS`

In both cases, `ITEM` will benefit from becoming the inner part of the join and an index from on the child will help support a loop join strategy.